# Postgres query for grouping series by boolean flag

Tags: postgresql

I have data like,

| index | flag |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | F |
| 1 | T |
| 2 | T |
| 3 | T |
| 4 | F |
| 5 | F |
| 6 | T |

And I want to write a Postgres query to convert this to,

| index | flag | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | F | 0 |
| 1 | T | 1 |
| 2 | T | 1 |
| 3 | T | 1 |
| 4 | F | 2 |
| 5 | F | 2 |
| 6 | T | 3 |

Where the group increments every time the flag changed between true and false.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `LAG()` and `SUM()` window functions:

```
SELECT "index", flag, SUM(r::int) OVER (ORDER BY "index") "group"
FROM (
  SELECT *, flag <> LAG(flag, 1, flag) OVER (ORDER BY "index") r
  FROM tablename
) t
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=1ba04ee25183b1468c5809c6c01b8d46).
Results:

| index | flag | group |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | f | 0 |
| 1 | t | 1 |
| 2 | t | 1 |
| 3 | t | 1 |
| 4 | f | 2 |
| 5 | f | 2 |
| 6 | t | 3 |